# CSVLines to JTextField in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I think this may have been answered but i cant seem to find what I'm looking for, so I apologize in advance if it has.

But I'm trying to get a saved CSVline (multiple) to read BACK to JtextFields when i run the program.

could someone plz help?

im running Eclipse Photon. 
im really new to all of this so any and all help would be great.

thanks.

Comment: What steps did you try at your end, can you mentioned more details like what you tried and what is not working?

Comment: i have turned my oirginal lines
(first name
second name
likes
dislikes
birthday)

all into a csv format and ran the save however, i cant seem to find anything on how to LOAD them back into the original format for viewing purposes.

Comment: Share what you have tried, what issue code is giving. Stack overflow is to find mistakes and help, not a free service where other's do your work.

Comment: i'm new to all of this, sorry. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

i had a mate rig this up for me in class so as not to have anyone write my code for me or spoonfeed me the answer.

[public void ReadRecord()
{
    Path filePath = Paths.get(INSERT_PATH); // Replace INSERT_PATH with the path to the file
    try // All is encased in a try / catch to handle an exception if the user does not select a file and click OK
    {
        // Read all lines of the file located at the filePath and assign it to a String List
        // Create and instantiate a new 2D String List

```
    // Create a foreach loop for each line that has been read from the file (Each line is in CSV format)
        // Create a String array and fill it with all items from the line split up
        // Create and instantiate a new String List

        // Create a foreach loop for each item in the String array
            // Add each item to the newly created String List
        // Add the String List to the 2D String List
    // Set the value of recordStore to the 2D String List
}
catch (Exception ex) { // Catch is always needed after a try statement to handle the exception
    ex.printStackTrace(); // This will print the Exception details to the debug output
}
```

}

i cant seem to understand exactly what it is and i was hoping that maybe, someone would be able to give me a better understanding or at least point me in the right direction to begin with this bit?